# Express app crash: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on express API application. I have roles in my system and for manage roles I have **Disable** option for each role. When I disable a role, there is an API endpoint for get disabled roles. It is,

`http://localhost:8080/role/disable/` -
This gives me all disabled roles.

And also I have getById endpoint for get **not disabled** role by passing roleId. It is,

`http://localhost:8080/role/:roleId` - This gives one role when I requested with roleId.

In order to get role I pass **roleId** as a param.

Currently I have several disabled roles and several not disabled roles in my database. My issue is when I request disabled roles via `http://localhost:8080/role/disable/` API endpoint, I get disabled roles as response. No issue on it.

But after processing the **getAllDisabled** endpoint, it calls **getById** endpoint. My logger file logged it. I figured that after processing **getAllDisabled** endpoint, the **getById** endpoint got word `disable` as roleId. Because **getById** endpoint need `roleId` ad a param. This happen because first part of both endpoint URLs are same as `http://localhost:8080/role/`.

My endpoints are these,

```
  // Get all disabled roles
  app.get('/role/disable', function (req, res, next) {
    reqLog(req, 'role.getAllDisabled');
    tokenAuthentication(req, res, next);
    checkIfSuperAdmin(req, res, next);
  },
    role.getAllDisabled
  );
```

```
  // Find role by id
  app.get('/role/:roleId', function (req, res, next) {
    reqLog(req, 'role.findById');
    next();
  },
    role.findById
  );
```

I got some middleware functions for authenticate requesting user also.

Can these endpoints make separate.

Comment: It may be because `tokenAuthentication` and `checkIfSuperAdmin` methods are setting headers one after another. Once a header is set it can't be set again which is what's causing an issue

Comment: Setting headers is not a problem. The problem is if you do a `res.write/end/stream/whatever()` that sends data to the client. You cannot set headers after sending any byte of data. If you see any HTML raw data flow, you will see headers going before the data, so cannot send headers after that. We don't actually see your code. We don't know if you are doing any res writting as we don't have your code, but just a small part of it.

Comment: `tokenAuthentication` and `checkIfSuperAdmin` methods do verify JWT token and check role of client using token payload. those functions do not set any headers. If there is a problem. Those functions send response back to client.

Comment: In my code I do not do any `res.write/end/stream/whatever()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got figured the issue. When `tokenAuthentication` middleware function check user **accessToken**, it add requesting user's info as `req.body.loggedUser` for further use. I use that data in other routes like update role route. In this time getting role data do not need user info. But this middleware method is shared one and I cannot change it. When I remove `tokenAuthentication` middleware it works fine. Issue is gone. But in order to do `checkIfSuperAdmin`, I need to authenticate user. I think to create a new method for `get` requests, but is there a way to do it without creating a new method? That would be grate.

So my main issue is gone but I still need to figure it out how to keep logged user info as temporary data.

Update :- Got an answer, I put `req.loggedUser` instead of `req.body.loggedUser`.